# Ambiguous or Unambiguous?

Tags: ambiguity

> a. John will arrive at the station in five minutes.
>
> b. John will eat the pizza in five minutes.
>
> c. John will play football in five minutes.

Which sentence triggers ambiguity? and How?

Comment: Please see our [guidelines for asking homework questions](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/346/300). Specifically, "make a good-faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first" and "ask about *specific* problems with your *existing* approach to answering the question".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"b" triggers ambiguity.  It is unclear if John will eat the pizza **within** five minutes (as in, for a duration of five minutes), or if he will **begin** to eat in the pizza after five minutes have passed.

As @WS2 mentioned, this ambiguity possibly exists in the others so I will attempt to explain why this makes the most sense.

In "a" the ambiguity does not exist.  Arriving in five minutes never implies arriving for a duration of five minutes.

In "c", John technically could play football for a duration of five minutes, but playing football is not an action you complete.  You could play " a game of football in five minutes " , and that would render a similar level of ambiguity as sentence "b".  When you play football for a duration of five minutes, you'd probably say " John will play football **for** five minutes"

Comment: Potentially the same problem exists with all three. Grammatically speaking they are all ambiguous. But it is just that the probable sense, in the other two cases, is clearer.

Comment: It doesn't exist in the first one, as far as I can tell.  And in the third, the sentence would sound awkward if it meant that he would play football for a duration of five minutes.  You'd generally use the word "for" instead of "in".